# jQuery validate additional methods on select combos drops error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form where I want to validate some dropdown combination(one field must have selected value) where the select combos are using selectpicker.

for this purpose I use jQuery validate with the additional methods

the validation script looks as it follows

```
var timesRegister = $('#registerTime').validate({

        ignore: '',
        debug: true,
        groups: {
            timeGroup: "hours minutes"
        },
        rules: {
            project_id: {
                required: true
            },
            datum: {
                required: true
            },
            hour: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".time-group"]
            },
            minutes: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".time-group"]
            }
        },

        messages: {
            project_id: "Please Select the working on Project!",
            datum: "Please enter working date!",
            //hour: "Please select the working hour/hours!",
            minutes: "Please select the working minutes!",
            hours_descr: "Please describe short the task!",
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                data: $(form).serialize()
                },
                success: function () {


                }, error: function (r) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

markup

```
<form method="POST" action="/times" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="registerTime" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="DezD0WQdWvXXW4If2xg5NhnAFd2vnkK6nNDXRUQ2">
    <input name="account_id" type="hidden" value="3423">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header ui-draggable-handle">
                <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>-->
                <h4 class="modal-title">Register your time!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" id="time-error"></div>


                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="project" class="control-label">Select Project</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="project_id">
                                      <option>Select Project</option>
                                      <option value="project1">Project</option>
                                      <option></option>
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="project" class="control-label">Select Day(s)</label>
                                    <div class="input-group date">
                                        <input name="datum" class="form-control input-sm" id="working_hours" type="text">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="hour" class="control-label">Select Hours</label>
                                    <select class="selectpicker time-group form-control" id="hour" name="hour">
                                      <option>0</option>
                                     <option value="1">1</option>
                                     <option value="2">2</option>
                                     <option value="3">3</option>
                                     <option value="4">4</option>
                                     <option value="5">5</option>
                                     <option value="6">6</option>

                                  </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="minutes" class="control-label">Select Minutes</label>
                                   <select class="selectpicker time-group form-control" id="minutes" name="minutes">
                                     <option>0</option>
                                     <option value="5">5</option>
                                     <option value="10">10</option>
                                     <option value="15">15</option>
                                     <option value="20">20</option>
                                     <option value="30">30</option>
                                     <option value="45">45</option>
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Description</label>
                                    <textarea name="hours_descr" id="" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-outline dark">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" id="submitTime" class="btn green">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

but drops me the following error
**Exception occurred when checking element hour, check the 'require_from_group' method.**

[codepen to reproduce](https://codepen.io/lgt/pen/eroMQb?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using jQuery Validate with `select` elements, the very first `option` **must** contain `value=""` or the plugin will already think an `option` is selected and the `required` rule will not be evaluated; for a `<select>`, it's the only rule that matters.

Adding `value=""` got some of your validation working, but it did not clear the console error(s).

The root cause is your `groups` option.  You specified `hours` here, which is undefined.

```
groups: {
    timeGroup: "hours minutes"
},
```

This should match your `select`, which is named `hour`...

```
groups: {
    timeGroup: "hour minutes"
},
```

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/v12rdyh6/](https://jsfiddle.net/v12rdyh6/)**